CS PhD admission with 99 on TOEFL where 100 is recommended
I'm planning to apply for the Fall admission this year in the US universities for a CS PhD offer as an international student.  While none of the universities require a minimum TOEFL score, many of them recommend a score of 100.  Unfortunately my score fell short by one: 99.  Retaking the exam would do quite a number on my wallet.  I'm not sure if I should retake the test.
Universities want more applications, as that brings in quite a lot of money.  So they have incentive to publish a lower minimum score but maintain a higher one internally.  My question is: Would a 99 be outright rejected where 100 is recommended?  Or will it be judged along with the other requirements, e.g., grades, research experience, LoR, etc.?

Different universities may choose a recommended score for different reasons. If you do not have too many schools on your list, I would write to the director of the relevant program (the CS program) to ask how a 99 vs. a 100 is interpreted in the admissions process. With their responses, you'll be able to decide whether or not to retake the test. (p.s. The reason to directly write to the CS program, and not the university general graduate admissions, is because the specific professors will often be more direct about how the applications are processed.)

@tkr That's an answer to the question and should be in the Answer box.

Different universities may choose a recommended score for different reasons. If you do not have too many schools on your list, I would write to the director of each relevant program (the CS program) to ask how a 99 vs. a 100 is interpreted in the admissions process. With their responses, you'll be able to decide whether or not to retake the test.
p.s. The reason to directly write to the CS program, and not the university general graduate admissions, is because the specific professors will often be more direct about how the applications are processed.

Universities always have people working in administration who know how the system really works and love to have their knowledge appreciated. So go ahead and ask. Just make sure that you are asking for information and not for special consideration.  Ask “how does this part of the system really work?” rather than “can you treat me as a special case?”.

I doubt that it will have any real effect. Only a few universities would reject on this basis, probably using an algorithm. Similarly for marginal GPA. Admission in the US is broad based and relies heavily on letters of recommendation.
What it might mean, however, and the same with GPA, is that if you have marginal numbers then your application might be considered later than others. And if they reach their quota there is no need to look very hard at others. Competition can be stiff, but other things than TOEFL are almost certainly more important.
And, had it been intended as an absolute cut-off it would almost certainly have been made clear.
BTW, you are wrong about universities wanting lots of applications because they generate quite a lot of money. In fact, they increase staff costs as well, and, at the scale of research institutions, application fees are minuscule.
